# Porque caracteres ASCII diferem do Excel para a apresentação por meio de código no VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, ascii

Alguém sabe por que isso ocorre?

Preciso usar caracteres da fonte "**Wingdings 3**" em **Labels** criados dinamicamente em um formulário do **VBA**.

Se estes **Labels** são criados diretamente no formulário o problema não ocorre, por exemplo, ao criar um **Label** e copiar o caractere desejado em seu Caption e selecionando a fonte "**Wingdings 3**", o **Label** apresenta o caractere corretamente, porém, ao usar **Chr(131)** no código para o Caption de um outro **Label**, surge algo como o caractere **Chr(156)** da mesma fonte (Invés de surgir uma seta cheia para a esquerda, surge uma seta pequena e fina para a direita).

O código abaixo lista alguns caracteres desta fonte, e fica claro que diferem totalmente dos caracteres **ASCII** do **Excel** acessados pelo Menu: **Inserir/Símbolos/Simbolo**.

Tem como resolver isso ou eu estou fazendo algo errado?

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim str As String

str = ""

For i = 33 To 255

  str = str & Chr(i)

Next i

Label1.Width = 500

Label1.Height = 500

Label1.Font.Name = "Wingdings 3"

Label1.Caption = str
```

Comment: Acima de 127 já não é ASCII, e passa a depender de saber a codificação usada pela interface que você está usando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução foi obtida assim:

Fiz um teste e coloquei **dois Labels** no formulário e **um deles** mudei a fonte para "**Wigdings 3**" e o outro ficou com "**Tahoma**".

**Pelo código**, **mudei a fonte dos dois Labels** para "**Wingdings 3**", mas ao enviar os mesmos **Chr(i)** com valores de **i** superiores a **127**, somente o **Label** com "**Wingdings 3**" mostrou os caracteres corretamente, ou seja, o comando que dei para mudar a fonte do **Label** não está sendo reconhecido na execução do código pelo **VBA**.

Portanto, para usar caracteres **ASCII** acima de **127** **por código** no **VBA**, deve-se colocar a mesma fonte desejada no objeto que receberá estes caracteres, senão, se estiverem parametrizados com outras fontes estes caracteres não corresponderão aos que são apresentados pelo **Excel** (Inserir/Símbolos/Simbolo), mesmo quando a fonte do objeto é alterada pelo código.